# How can I write emoji on Node.Js

Tags: mysql, node.js, encoding, emoji, utf8mb4

I use Node.js, MYSQL and want to write emoji.

My MYSQL's character set and collation all sets on 'utf8mb4'
and when I insert emoji with SQL, I can see emoji well.
(Probably It means There's no problem in MYSQL settings)

But When I send emoji with Postman or application which using node.js,
emoji is converted into '?' (question mark).

Here is my dbconfig.js.

```
const mysql = require('promise-mysql')
require('dotenv').config();

const dbConfig = {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE, // insert db name
    dateStrings: process.env.DB_DATESTRINGS,
    charset: 'utf8mb4'
}

module.exports = mysql.createPool(dbConfig)
```

What more should I do?

Comment: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ and https://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: From within the code, display `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`  (It can be run like a `SELECT`, retrieving rows and columns.)

Comment: The problem is probably in another place.  Check "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored Also do the debugging suggested about `SELECT HEX(col)`; the inserts may have been wrong, but your debugging so far had "two wrongs making a right".

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks for all of your comments.
I fixed it through Procedure Settings.
My error was caused cuz I used procedure and didn't set utf8mb4 on procedure.
Thanks